# Python-Mysql tinkter --Error: 1064 (42000)

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

Following code is two function design for delete/search data in mysql database. I get issue with following error message:

**Delete Error message**

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1

**Search Function Error message**

errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''%1%'' at line 1

Can someone advise here ?

```
#========DeleteFunction==============
def delete_data(self):
        con = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="123456", database="stm")
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("DELETE FROM students WHERE roll_no=%s",self.Roll_No_var.get())
        con.commit()
        con.close()
        self.fetch_data()
        self.clear()

#==========SearchFunction============    
def search_data(self):
        con=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="123456",database="stm")
        cur = con.cursor()

        cur.execute("select * from students where"+str(self.search_by.get())+"LIKE '%"+str(self.search_txt.get())+"%'")
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        if len(rows) != 0:
            self.Student_table.delete(*self.Student_table.get_children())
            for row in rows:
                self.Student_table.insert("", END, values=row)
            con.commit()
        con.close()
```

Comment: your delete sql command should  be ```cur.execute("DELETE FROM students WHERE roll_no=%s" % self.Roll_No_var.get())```

Comment: in the search function, you need a space after ```where``` and before ```LIKE```.   as it stands, it'll just say ```... where<searchstringresult>...```

Comment: Thanks. The first function works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lay in the sql statements:

```
cur.execute("DELETE FROM students WHERE roll_no=%s",self.Roll_No_var.get())
```

should be

```
cur.execute("DELETE FROM students WHERE roll_no=%s" % self.Roll_No_var.get())
```

and

```
cur.execute("select * from students where"+str(self.search_by.get())+"LIKE '%"+str(self.search_txt.get())+"%'")
```

should be:

```
cur.execute("select * from students where "+str(self.search_by.get())+" LIKE '%"+str(self.search_txt.get())+"%'")
```

Comment: Better use `cur.execute("DELETE FROM students WHERE roll_no = %s", (self.Roll_No_var.get(),))` (using placeholder) for first case.

Comment: i would recommend to do parameter substitution to keep the code short